# How to calculate velocity if sprint backlog has tasks which are not directly related with stories in product backlog?

Tags: scrum

I have a product backlog with some features and a sprint backlog which includes tasks for these features, and also such tasks which are not directly related with stories in product backlog (for example, testing, "to connect to db", "to do interface design" and so on). How can I calculate the velocity then?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Estimate them and treat them as planned work. Not ideal, since these "tasks" don't yield direct value ot the product backlog, but it sounds like work and the product backlog contains all the work that could be done to deliver the product...
2. Ignore them and treat them as overhead, your velocity will be lower, but that's ok, the velocity then tells you how much work you've been able to deliver that adds value. These other tasks are just "overhead". Or they'd be part of what's commonly called Refinement.

Of course the better solution would be to slice your work in such a way that these tasks are part of delivering the value for that sprint.

Comment: There is a third option. Wrap the technical tasks in to business value delivering stories.

Comment: @BarnabyGolden of course. I was seem to have ignored this option because in my mind that would have been so obvious ;).